# How to observe scheduled tasks output with Django celery and Docker

Tags: django, docker, celery, django-celery

I have setup my celery app for django and trying to test a simple periodic tasks in my django app.

I have used RabbitMQ as message broker and setup `broker_url` by passing environment variables from `docker-compose.yml` file as well.

I have following structure in `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: NGINX
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: DJANGO
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn loop.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - db
      - rabbit

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: PSQL

  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    ports:
      # We forward this port for debugging purposes.
      - "5672:5672" 
      # Here, we can access the rabbitmq management plugin.
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass

   # Celery worker
  worker:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py celery worker -B --concurrency=1"
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    links:
      - db
      - rabbit
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
```

For testing purpose, I have created a schedule tasks in settings.py as follows:(scheduling for 10 seconds)

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'schedule-task': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.test_print',
        'schedule': 10,  # in seconds
    },
}
```

and the tasts.py file inside myapp has following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery.task import task

@task(ignore_result=True, max_retries=1, default_retry_delay=10)
def test_print():
    print ("Print from celery task")
```

When I run command : `docker-compose run web python manage.py celery worker -B --concurrency=1`
The `test_print` is executed and the output is printed.

But when I run `docker-compose up --build`, the following output is printed. But, the tasks `test_print` is not executed?

```
rabbit_1  | =INFO REPORT==== 15-Jun-2017::13:05:30 ===
rabbit_1  | accepting AMQP connection <0.354.0> (172.18.0.7:51400 -> 172.18.0.3:5672)

rabbit_1  | =INFO REPORT==== 15-Jun-2017::12:54:25 ===
rabbit_1  | connection <0.421.0> (172.18.0.6:52052 -> 172.18.0.3:5672): user 'admin' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

I am new to docker. Any guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: did you know Celery ? with you can see all youre scheduled tasks and output in a web view

Comment: You have different volumes in web and worker services. Have you checked that?

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I did blunder on that part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MaximeK , Yes, I do know celery. I am just trying to see the output of my test function while running up command in docker.